# Phasor form and complex notation of fields

Tags: electromagnetism

Is the phasor form the same as the complex notation for an electric field?

I know that the physical electric field is the real part of the electric field in complex notation. Does that mean the complex notation can only be used when E has both spatial and time dependence, and not just spatial?
And where does the phasor form come in?

The lack of clarity on this is making me extremely confused. Any help is appreciated.